# Keyboard shortcut for saving and closing Query Builder window in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, shortcuts

Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> while keyboard cursor are in the input box `Provider Specific Filter Expression` creates new line.

**How to save and close Query Builder window in QGIS 3 without mouse?**

This doesn't work:

<kbd>Ctrl + Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd>,

<kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Alt + F4</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl + S + Alt + F4</kbd>  only closes the window, but does not save the results.

[image]

Comment: Did you try `Alt` + `F4`?

Comment: @Taras Thx, it closes the window but doesn't save results (same as `Esc`).

Comment: Does this work `Ctrl` + `S` and after `Alt` + `F4`?

Comment: @Taras No, it dosen't work.